# Implement BBCode to utilise AppBrain's app widget

Tags: feature-request, linking, qr-codes

Hey guys,

I know when we recommend apps we usually link them to AppBrain. The issue here is the minor inconsistency with the links. I like to link the app and also insert the QR code.

AppBrain have a nice simple app widget as seen below which has all the app information plus a link to the QR code.

[image: AppBrain's app widget]

Is there a possibility to implement BBCode to allow users to copy and paste the BBCode app widget?

Comment: This would be nice

Comment: I think this feature request should be for AppBrain to generate a code generator that can be easily copy-pasted to AE (IOW, to Markdown syntax). Otherwise, browser addon would be a much better fit for this.

Comment: This would be nice, but it sounds like making core changes to the SE engine won't come about easily. Can anyone more talented in Markdown generate an example that we can propose to AppBrain for inclusion on their site?

Answer (score 2):

While that's pretty cool, AppBrain is not the only market out there, and it is a for-profit venture. I think it's fine for users to link to wherever they want, I don't think the site itself should be seen as giving any site preferential treatment. If we add markup for AppBrain to the editor, we'd have to add markup for all other sites, as well.

Not unless there's some form of kickback for the moderators, that is! I'd like a Nexus One and a 32GB SD card, please.

At any rate, I don't think that we can customize an individual SE site at that level.

Comment: I don't see why SE can't give preferntial treatment to a site that is favored by the majority of it's users.  It's not as though he's suggesting that we block all other market aggregators, he's just suggesting that we add markdown to make it easier for SE users to link to the aggregator that is already the most frequently linked to. Also, BB Code isn't specific to Appbrain. If any of the other app aggregating sites like androlib or androidtapp decided to offer bb code widgets then they could join in the fun.

Comment: So, because they're the biggest for-profit site, we should help them -- for free -- continue to be the biggest for-profit site? Plus, it would look, quite rightly, like Institutional favoritism. Kinda throws the throws any pretense of objectivism out the window. If they pay for such treatment, and that was acknowledged, it would be a different story.

Comment: I think you're fighting the wrong fight here mate. If AE implements BBCode then people like me could use sites like AppBrain to add app widgets to my answers. It's not about using AppBrain but they do have a nice app widget that is compact and present all the information a user would need. Like Matt said, BBCode isn't specific to AppBrain so therefore you don't have to use it with AppBrain only... but people like me would get the benefit of BBCode since I use AppBrain to link the apps I recommend in my answers.

Comment: @mlevit -- Sorry, the whole "utilise AppBrain's app widget" in the question sure looks like something via AppBrain. It's not clear to me how this can be used for other sites. If it can be, it needs to be explained clearly, with examples.

Comment: BBCode isn't unique to AppBrain therefore it can be used with any other service that provides BBCode to format whatever information you'd like to display.

Answer (score 1):

What would be better, IMHO, would be something added to the `Insert Hyperlink` box that would generate a QR Code in addition to, or instead of, the regular URL.  QR Codes can be generated to represent any text, so it would be a natural fit (again, IMHO).

Comment: It would be nice... but the only issue with that is we would have to generate the actual Android Market URL in order for the QR code to work.

Comment: No, you simply convert whatever is put in the URL line to a QR code.  For example: http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=Now%20is%20the%20time%20for%20all%20good%20men%20to%20come%20to%20the%20aid%20of%20their%20country.